# android application terminates unexpectedly

Tags: android

I'm running a web service android and inserts all correctly, but when the application terminates unexpectedly end.

Anyone know why?

this is the code ...

```
 protected Void doInBackground(final Void... unused) {


   Opdblevantamiento info = new Opdblevantamiento(SyndatlevwsAsyncTask.this);
    info.Abrir();
    Cursor c = info.recibirLevantamiento();
    //-----------------------------------
    int fila;
    String cc02="",cc03="",cc04="",cc05="";
    String cc06="",cc07="",cc08="", cc09="",cc10="";
    String cc11="",cc12="",cc13="", cc14="";

    //-----------------------------------

    int c01=c.getColumnIndex(ID_FILA);
    int c02=c.getColumnIndex(NCTA);
    int c03=c.getColumnIndex(NOMBREPROP);
    int c04=c.getColumnIndex(COLONIA);
    int c05=c.getColumnIndex(CALLE);
    int c06=c.getColumnIndex(DAT_A);
    int c07=c.getColumnIndex(DAT_B);
    int c08=c.getColumnIndex(DAT_C);
    int c09=c.getColumnIndex(DAT_D);
    int c10=c.getColumnIndex(DAT_E);
    int c11=c.getColumnIndex(INFRAESTRUCTURA);
    int c12=c.getColumnIndex(NOMBREPRED);
    int c13=c.getColumnIndex(FECHA);
    int c14=c.getColumnIndex(HORA);     


    //String resultado2="Cuentas No Generadas: \n";
    //String resultado = "Cuentas Generadas con Éxito: \n";
    String datWs=null;

    for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext())
    {
        fila=Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c01));
        cc02=c.getString(c02).toString();
        cc03=c.getString(c03).toString();
        cc04=c.getString(c04).toString();
        cc05=c.getString(c05).toString();
        cc06=c.getString(c06).toString();
        cc07=c.getString(c07).toString();
        cc08=c.getString(c08).toString();
        cc09=c.getString(c09).toString();
        cc10=c.getString(c10).toString();
        cc11=c.getString(c11).toString();
        cc12=c.getString(c12).toString();
        cc13=c.getString(c13).toString();
        cc14=c.getString(c14).toString();

        datWs=consumiendoWsLevantamiento(cc02,cc03,cc04,cc05,cc06,cc07,cc08,cc09,cc10,cc11,cc12,cc13,cc14);
         Log.i("wsInicio", datWs);
        if(datWs != null)
        {
            long datUpd=info.updatelev(fila);
            if(datUpd>0)
            {
                //Toast.makeText(this, "Registro registrado exitosamente: " + cc02 , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //resultado=resultado+"::"+cc02+"::  \n";
                System.out.println("Folio Insertado: [" + datWs + "]");
                publishProgress("Cuenta Registrada: " + cc02);

                //this.dialog.setMessage("Folio Insertado: [" + datWs + "]");
                //onProgressUpdate(Integer.parseInt(datWs)); // Invokes onProgressUpdate()
                // this.dialog.show();
            }                   

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error ws: " + datWs);
            publishProgress("Error de conexión no se pudo registrar la cuenta: " + cc02);
            LevantamientoTask.this.cancel(true);
        }
            //resultado2=resultado2+"||"+cc02+"||"+" ."+datWs + ". \n";

    }

    info.cerrar();


    //resultado = resultado + resultado2;

    //txtdat.setText(String.valueOf(resultado));
    //txtdat2.setText(String.valueOf(resultado2));

   //String auth=doLogin(t_id,password);
   //System.out.println(auth);

   return null; // don't interact with the ui!
```

}

and error console .....

```
04-04 18:11:14.828: D/dalvikvm(32008): GC_CONCURRENT freed 316K, 6% free 7676K/8135K, paused 14ms+6ms
04-04 18:11:26.977: D/dalvikvm(32008): GC_CONCURRENT freed 434K, 7% free 7696K/8263K, paused 3ms+5ms
04-04 18:11:38.048: I/dalvikvm(32008): Jit: resizing JitTable from 512 to 1024
04-04 18:11:44.318: D/dalvikvm(32008): GC_CONCURRENT freed 437K, 7% free 7706K/8263K, paused 10ms+22ms
04-04 18:11:55.588: D/dalvikvm(32008): GC_CONCURRENT freed 418K, 7% free 7694K/8263K, paused 4ms+4ms
04-04 18:11:59.208: D/dalvikvm(32008): GREF has increased to 201
04-04 18:11:59.718: D/dalvikvm(32008): GC_CONCURRENT freed 346K, 7% free 7799K/8327K, paused 13ms+12ms
04-04 18:12:20.328: D/dalvikvm(32008): GC_CONCURRENT freed 502K, 8% free 7738K/8391K, paused 12ms+35ms
04-04 18:12:26.318: I/dalvikvm(32008): Jit: resizing JitTable from 1024 to 2048
04-04 18:12:32.997: D/dalvikvm(32008): GC_CONCURRENT freed 400K, 8% free 7733K/8391K, paused 12ms+4ms
04-04 18:12:43.168: D/dalvikvm(32008): GC_CONCURRENT freed 399K, 8% free 7734K/8391K, paused 10ms+4ms
04-04 18:12:53.278: D/dalvikvm(32008): GC_CONCURRENT freed 400K, 8% free 7739K/8391K, paused 4ms+5ms
04-04 18:13:05.487: D/dalvikvm(32008): GC_CONCURRENT freed 408K, 8% free 7742K/8391K, paused 12ms+5ms
04-04 18:13:15.358: D/dalvikvm(32008): GC_CONCURRENT freed 337K, 7% free 7808K/8391K, paused 9ms+11ms
04-04 18:13:18.118: I/System.out(32008): NuevoLevantamiento{c1=55555; c2=kkkkk; c3=kkkk; c4=kkkkk; c5=|01|09|07|2009|10|; c6=; c7=; c8=; c9=; c10=|true|false|true|false|true|; c11=hhhh; c12=04/04/2013; c13=18:11:59S; }
04-04 18:13:18.618: I/levantemiento(32008): 35
04-04 18:13:18.618: I/System.out(32008): response35
04-04 18:13:18.618: I/System.out(32008): 35
04-04 18:13:18.618: I/wsInicio(32008): 35
04-04 18:13:18.651: I/System.out(32008): Folio Insertado: [35]
04-04 18:13:18.670: I/System.out(32008): NuevoLevantamiento{c1=5555; c2=rrrrr; c3=xc; c4=xa; c5=|02|00|00|2007|480|; c6=; c7=; c8=; c9=; c10=|true|false|true|false|true|; c11=yyy; c12=04/04/2013; c13=18:13:08S; }
04-04 18:13:18.877: I/levantemiento(32008): 36
04-04 18:13:18.877: I/System.out(32008): response36
04-04 18:13:18.877: I/System.out(32008): 36
04-04 18:13:18.877: I/wsInicio(32008): 36
04-04 18:13:18.908: I/System.out(32008): Folio Insertado: [36]
04-04 18:13:18.928: D/AndroidRuntime(32008): Shutting down VM
04-04 18:13:18.928: W/dalvikvm(32008): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
04-04 18:13:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(32008): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 18:13:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(32008): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-04 18:13:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(32008):    at jmatias.levantamiento.SyndatlevwsAsyncTask$LevantamientoTask.onPostExecute(SyndatlevwsAsyncTask.java:280)
04-04 18:13:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(32008):    at jmatias.levantamiento.SyndatlevwsAsyncTask$LevantamientoTask.onPostExecute(SyndatlevwsAsyncTask.java:1)
04-04 18:13:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(32008):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:590)
04-04 18:13:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(32008):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:149)
04-04 18:13:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(32008):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:603)
04-04 18:13:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(32008):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-04 18:13:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(32008):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
04-04 18:13:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(32008):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
04-04 18:13:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(32008):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 18:13:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(32008):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
04-04 18:13:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(32008):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
04-04 18:13:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(32008):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
04-04 18:13:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(32008):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 18:18:18.988: I/Process(32008): Sending signal. PID: 32008 SIG: 9
```

Comment: plz add relevant part of code because problem is inside `onPostExecute` method instead of `doInBackground`

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming in the onPostExecute() part of your AsyncTask which you didn't post the code for. If you look at the stack trace it is telling you the error is on line 280 in that method. You are calling a method on something which is NULL in that line.

Comment: Thanks friend, the error was Log.i ("levonPostExecute" result.toString ());

regards